# How do I get my programme to work with the function ob_start();?

Tags: php

I am student (not long being doing PHP so don't know a lot about PHP) but I am trying to get my code to work, at first it was working fine, until it was transfer to a different server but since it had I was getting the following error:

'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/deanj/public_html/login.php:21) in /home/deanj/public_html/login.php on line 60'.

Then I got suggested to use ob_start(); so I tried to use it but didnt get much good results. So what do I need to do use this? and is it the best option? if not what is?

p.s. please make it as simple as you can.

Comment: You should change your script so whatever you do on line 60 is done before line 21 (because when the document has started outputting, you can't send any headers any more.)

Comment: Did you put ob_start() at beginning of your php file?

Comment: @adam that's a dirty fix for a problem that should be solved at its root.

Comment: Probably appeared new line after closed tag ?> which is sending to browser before headers, or appeared a php notice which sends to output. Try to setup ini_set('display_errors', 0) to disable errors and see if cause in this

Comment: @pekka I agree, but i have feeling that with this code it is probably  a tip of iceberg of bad practices ( no offence to user2962093 :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini set output buffering to On. You should NOT have to modify your code using ob_start() since it is clearly an environment issue. The key to knowing that is in your question, "it was working fine, until it was transfer to a different server".

To fix it, in your php.ini file you want:

output_buffering = On

http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php

That is also likely why the same code worked on one server, but not on your new one (since output buffering was configured differently).

Comment: This is a really poor workaround for a problem that should be fixed at its root: changing the script's logic so it doesn't output anything before headers are sent. Output buffering makes page output slower

Comment: I completely agree, but how is that related to my answer? My answer doesn't change the logic, it changes the PHP setup which was obviously different between the two servers.

Comment: So your advice is instead of fixing the actual problem, to activate the workaround? That's not necessarily the best advice to give to a PHP learner and everyone else who looks at this question in the future.

Comment: Read the question, "it was working fine, until it was transfer to a different server"... you shouldn't be suggesting he modifies his code under that situation.

Comment: I disagree. That's *exactly* what you should be suggesting to avoid using a dirty and performance-weakening workaround. Especially to a learner.

Comment: Using output buffering speeds up performance (buffers generally increase performance)! What are you on about :/